# How to mock user state in bot 4 unit test?

Tags: c#, botframework

I am using User Profile to send user data to bot dialog from unit test project.
But i get empty user profile in dialog.

Test Project:

```
var conversationStateAccessors = _ConversationState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
                var conversationData = await conversationStateAccessors.GetAsync(turn, () => new UserProfile());
                conversationData.UserEmailId = "vikash.ranjan.jha";
                conversationData.UserName = "vikash";
                await _ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turn, false, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>());
```

Bot Dialog:

```
_userProfileAccessor = conversationState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));

var userProfile = await _userProfileAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, () => new UserProfile(), cancellationToken);
```

This user profile is empty.

Answer (score 0):

User Azure Blob Storage instead of local memory storage

```
services.AddSingleton<IStorage, MemoryStorage>();
```